# How to inner join tables with mysql & php with same id?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables `table_1` and `table_2`.

**table_1**

```
id               name              date
--------------------------------------------------------
1111111111      product 1         1.12.2013
2222222222      product 2         2.4.1995
3333333333      product 3         1.2.2016
```

**table_2**

```
id      name       date          t_id
--------------------------------------------------------
1      abc         1.1.2013    1111111111
2      def         2.4.1995    2222222222
3      ghi         1.2.2016    2222222222
4      abc         1.1.2013    3333333333
5      def         2.4.1995    1111111111
6      ghi         1.2.2016    1111111111
```

I wanna `SELECT name, date FROM table_2;`
but the value I want is when `table_1.id = table_2.t_id`.
Please, explain me how I can do this with php, mysql. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you want is just a simple join between the two tables:

```
SELECT t2.id,
       t2.name,
       t2.date,
       COALESCE(t1.name, 'NA') AS productName,
       COALESCE(t1.date, 'NA') AS productDate
FROM table_2 t2
LEFT JOIN table_1 t1
    ON t1.id = t2.t_id
```

By the way, your dates are stored in a weird format, in `varchar`.  You should switch to use a standard MySQL format.  For example, instead of `1.12.2013` in a `varchar` column, you should have `2013-01-12` in some sort of `date` column.

**Demo Here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: thanks Tim, dont worry for MySql format, this is just example. What i wanna know is you use t2,t1 what is that? is it the same with tablename? and what is 'NA'?

Comment: `t2` and `t1` are aliases, which can be used in place of actual table names.  I used `NA` as default text in case `table_1` does not match to `table_2`.

Comment: You can see that he defines these aliases as soon as he calls on the table in question `FROM table_2 t2` and `LEFT JOIN table_1 t1`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using mysql query:

```
select table_2.name, table_2.date FROM table_1 left join table_2 on table_1.id = table_2.t_id;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Lovepreet, it's work but it's return all of the row from table_2. What i want is when table_1 id(Primary key) match with table_2 t_id ⇒ return all of the row that have the same t_id with table_1 id, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute 2 queries, first the id retrieval from the table 1
and the second query for name and date retrieval from table 2

```
$query ="SELECT id FROM table_1"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query Failed".mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $query_1 ="SELECT name,date FROM table_2 WHERE t_id='$row[id]'"; 
  $result_1 = mysql_query($query_1) or die("Query Failed".mysql_error());
  $row_1=mysql_fetch_array($result_1);
  print_r($row_1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else who might have a similar problem, this might help.

```
SELECT table2.columnname, table2.columnname from table1, table2 where table1.id = table2.id
```

the ID columns should have the same values but different names for this to work without using join.